# c system calls being ran before the if statement

Tags: c

So here is my problem, given this code, just about anything added before the please input your name is ignored, and automatically the first instruction that is run(without even first checking if x is 5, is input your name, then the instructions prior to it are run. So if the first line of the program was a printf, that would be ignored and immediately it would ask for input then print the printf statement even though it was first. please help

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char val[70];
    int x=3;
    if(x>5)
    {
        if(write(1, "Please input your name", 22)!=22)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if(read(0, val, 36) < 0)
        {}

        if(write(1, val, 36)!=36)
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 is not greater than 5.

Answer (score 1):

printf works on `stdout` which is a FILE*. The read() and write() calls work directly on file descriptors.

A FILE* is usually buffered, meaning the stuff you printf resides in a buffer in your program until it is flushed. While write() sends the data directly to the operating system, without any buffering in your application.

So flush the FILE* buffer to make output appear:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char val[70];
  int x=3;
  printf("Hello");
  fflush(stdout);
```

And if stdout is your terminal, it is usually auto flushed when you write a newline, e.g.   `printf("Hello\n");`

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is not what happens. Your main function will immediately return 0. Here is an example debugging in:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40074b: file ./test.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/test 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe528) at ./test.cpp:6
6       int x=3;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.16-28.fc18.x86_64 libgcc-4.7.2-8.fc18.x86_64 libstdc++-4.7.2-8.fc18.x86_64
(gdb) next
7       if(x>5)
(gdb) 
19  }
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7744a05 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) 
Single stepping until exit from function __libc_start_main,
which has no line number information.
[Inferior 1 (process 4962) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

In fact, with optimizations enabled, the whole `if` check with its body is eliminated as a dead code, resulting in a nice main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Which is confirmed by looking at the binary code (`objdump -CD -M intel`):

```
00000000004004c0 <main>:
  4004c0:       31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  4004c2:       c3                      ret    
  4004c3:       90                      nop
```

Perhaps it is a good time for you to learn how to debug your code. Start by reading some [GDB documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/).

Good Luck!